# How to install a software 5 times in linux?

Tags: multithreading

The software(let's name it SW) has complex dependencies. I do not know whether it is enough if I just install SW 5 times in different directories.

My motivation is multi-thread running. If only one SW is installed, common-parameters may be shared between different threads.

Could docker help? Then the five SW could be independent of each other completely.

But I want a way that the 5 SW really occupy disk space in the host. It is not just 5 containers are used.

Comment: Off-topic here. And completely unrelated to multi-threading.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Many complex free software can be configured to be installed with some specific name or suffix.

For exemple, many GNU programs (and some non-GNU ones) have a `configure` script produced by [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf). In that case, try `configure --help` at first. You probably can use [`--prefix`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Installation-Names.html#Installation-Names)  and/or [`--program-suffix`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Optional-Features.html#Optional-Features)

So, for an [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf)-ed program with some `configure` script, you could build it five times with five different `--program-suffix`  strings. See also [GNU stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).

For [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) programs not using such `configure` scripts, you need to read their documentation and source code. Most of the time their documentation explains how to configure them for such purposes. But you can still improve their source code for your needs.

For proprietary programs, you should dive into their documentation, and discuss with the vendor (perhaps paying him to adapt his software to your needs).

BTW, your question is unrelated to multi-[threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) (e.g. to [Posix threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)).

Comment: You mean I can install it several times via giving them different names?